# Am I able to track all new answers?

Tags: support

I see answers to old questions in the review queue, but these are just the answers from users new to the site.

Is there any way I can see all new answers on the site ?

Comment: In the site, or as an RSS feed?

Comment: @curiousdannii Pardon my ignorance, I am not familiar with what RSS means.

Comment: A website feed you add to a feed reader. Often used for blogs. Not knowing what it is is a good enough answer though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use feedly to subscribe to the RSS feed like curioudannii suggested, if you find a news aggregator that you like and point it at the site it'll pick up some default RSS (really simple syndication) feeds and display them there.

But if you don't want to do this, you can bookmark this search:

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer

Comment: Excellent. That does the trick. Thank you very much.